# C# use SHA1 to hash string into byte array

Tags: c#, encryption, sha1

I'm using SHA1 to encrypt some values like password.
This is my code:

```
String passwd = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 2);
SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte [] password = sha.ComputeHash(passwd);
```

But VS returns error, because passwd is a string.
I have to store the password in a byte array, so is there a way to solve this?

Comment: SHA1 is not an encryption algorithm.  You mean hash.

Comment: You are using unsalted SHA1, just like LinkedIn in the past. As you might have heard, that didn't work out too well for them. Instead use [bcrypt](https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/), it slows down password crackers a couple orders of magnitude and has built-in salting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
String passwd = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 2);
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwd);
SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte [] password = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
```

Note that SHA1 does not encrypt data but hash them instead. Encrypted data can be decrypted. Hash algorithms are one way.

Comment: Although @tvanfosson got it correctly first, +1 from me for enhancing your answer after being accepted.

Comment: byte[] password = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)); as a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Encoding to convert the string to a byte array

```
var bytes= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwd);
var password = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
```

Comment: I would change the variable name to **encoded**, otherwise this is a bit confusing, isn't it?

Comment: The new name **bytes** is much better. And I'd go with your answer using `UTF8` rather that the accepted answer with `Unicode`. You beat me to it, so +1 from me ;).